# Project 2013 CSOM, How to add indentation to entries to lookup table

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, project-server, csom

I am trying to add hierarchical set of lookup entries to a lookup table. But all the entries come in a single level. I am using managed client object model for the same. How do I implement indentation ?

```
            LookupTableCreationInformation linfo = new LookupTableCreationInformation();
            linfo.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            linfo.Name = "Test 01";
            linfo.SortOrder = LookupTableSortOrder.Ascending;

            LookupMask mask = new LookupMask();
            mask.Length = 2;
            mask.MaskType = LookupTableMaskSequence.CHARACTERS;
            mask.Separator = ".";

            LookupMask mask2 = new LookupMask();
            mask2.Length = 5;
            mask2.MaskType = LookupTableMaskSequence.CHARACTERS;
            mask2.Separator = ".";


            LookupEntryCreationInformfation LCntCrInf = new LookupEntryCreationInformation();
            LCntCrInf.Description = "Test";
            var id = Guid.NewGuid();
            LCntCrInf.Id = id;
            LCntCrInf.Value = new LookupEntryValue();
            LCntCrInf.Value.TextValue = "Aa";

            LookupEntryCreationInformation EntryInfo2 = new LookupEntryCreationInformation();
            EntryInfo2.Value = new LookupEntryValue();
            EntryInfo2.Value.TextValue = "Bb";
            EntryInfo2.ParentId = id;
            EntryInfo2.Description ="level2";
            EntryInfo2.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

            List<LookupEntryCreationInformation> lcreInfo = new List<LookupEntryCreationInformation>();
            List<LookupMask> lmaskCreIf = new List<LookupMask>();

            lmaskCreIf.Add(mask);
            lmaskCreIf.Add(mask2);

            lcreInfo.Add(LCntCrInf);
            lcreInfo.Add(EntryInfo2);

            linfo.Masks = lmaskCreIf;
            linfo.Entries = lcreInfo;

            ctx.LookupTables.Update();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

In the code I am adding two masks, and then two entries. I am assigning to the parent id of the second entry, the id of the first entry.

It doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Seems it works fine, issue was while assigning a guid to the id of the entries, i was using `new Guid()` instead of `Guid.NewGuid()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seemed to work fine for me:

[image: lookup test]

I just had to add the following to actually add the table:
    ctx.LookupTables.Add(linfo);

Comment: Ya it is, silly mistake on my part :/